# How to lose your main weapon in Assassins creed 2?

Tags: assassins-creed-2

I was fighting with a scimitar and suddenly I noticed I'm actually fighting with a common sword. How do I drop this weapon and pick up a guards weapon? I wanna pick up an axe or spear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some guard must have knocked the weapon out of your hand and you grabbed another weapon.

There are two ways to acquire another weapon: the first is to get one from the ground, after you have killed its owner. You must switch to Unarmed (down on the D-Pad) and press the pick-up button (Y or Triangle, IIRC).

Another is to disarm your enemy. Using Unarmed, you must perform a counter-attack (RT+X or R2+Square) when your enemy attacks you. Note that boss enemies can't be disarmed and some attacks can't be countered.